# Disconnecting headphones with audiokit running gives malloc error with AKOperationEffect specifically

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, headphones

// My code is below

```
do{
    file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Sound1.mp3", baseDir: .resources)
    //    file =  try AKAudioFile(forReading: SingletonClass.sharedInstance.recordedURLs[SingletonClass.sharedInstance.recordedURL]!)

    //     AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
}
catch {

}

do {
    player = try AKAudioPlayer(file : file)

}
catch {

}

let lfoAmplitude = 1_000
let lfoRate = 1.0 / 3.428

_ = 0.9

//filter section effect below
filterSectionEffect = AKOperationEffect(tracker) { input, _ in
    let lfo = AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: lfoRate, amplitude: lfoAmplitude)
    return input.moogLadderFilter(cutoffFrequency: lfo + cutoffFrequency,
                                  resonance: resonance)
}
Audiokit.output = filterSectionEffect
Audiokit.start()
```

And whenever I play the audio using a button with code player.play , the audio gets played properly. And if I connect the headphones, it gets played properly as well but as soon as I disconnect the headphones, I see the error:

[image: Image showing the error]

It happens in same way for both wired as well as bluetooth headphones. 
My app with stuck because of this issue only that too happens only with `AKOperationEffect`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  Instead, I think you've found a legitimate bug in AudioKit.  It seems to handle the first audio route change okay, but then have troubles the second time around. I'm not yet sure of the fix, but I wanted to at least acknowledge that we're probably at fault here, not your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, its just second time audio route change issue.

Comment: This issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Kunal Verma that this is fixed is correct, but just for completeness here is the commit that fixed it.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/ffac4acbe93553764f6095011e9bf5d71fdc88c2